In my old chest freezer, why did the frequency and amplitude of temperature fluctuations change over time?
I have an old Kenmore chest freezer model C675-1902-0L manufactured in 2004 and still running fine. I recently put a remote temperature monitor in it and found the pattern of fluctuation shown in the attached time graph. Most of the time, the frequency of fluctuation in temperature is about 10-12 hours and the amplitude of fluctuation is about 2 degrees celcius (C), as shown at the beginning and end of the graph. But for 3.5 days in the middle, the frequency increased to about 40 minutes, and the amplitude decreased to 0.5 degrees C or less. Note that all the temperatures recorded were just fine; that is, lower than -18.5 degrees C. Since 30 November, the fluctuation has been stable. Why did this occur? Does this indicate an impending problem?

Update
Regarding ambient temperature fluctuation, the freezer is in the basement which, although not directly heated, is comfortable year around. Here in Victoria, BC, the outdoor temperature doesn't fluctuate that much, as shown in the attached graph.
Regarding freezer use, we hardly ever open the top, and I am very careful to be sure that it is completely closed after the rare opening.
I will continue to watch the temperature with the remote temperature monitor and replace the thermostat is there's any further idiocyncratic behaviour.


It's a 20 year old freezer, don't you think it will show some signs of aging?

I’m voting to close this question because it is only on the fringes of home improvement and not truly part of the flavor of what we do here.

bruh, seriously, your worried about a less than a 2° fluctuation?  how do you know that did not happen on this thing when new or the same thing does not happen on any other new freezer.  not to mention... what would cause the interior temperature to rise?  did it ever occur to monitor external temperature?

I know if I was there, i'd definitely open the thing periodically just to mess with your temp recording... you did not mention anything about the environment this thing is located in.

If you did the same technical checks with your homes electrical system you would drive yourself crazy.   ( Who does this?)

I would speculate it's erratic operation of the new temperature probe, as long as we're in speculation mode here.

Wow, I just posed a simple question. I didn't think I'd get back a bunch of snarky feedback. To address said feedback:


Of course it may show signs of aging. I wanted to know if this change in frequency and amplitude was one of those signs; 2) I posted this question where I found a dozen other questions about freezers; 3) The question was NOT about the absolute amplitude of temperature fluctuation, it was about the sudden and substantial change in amplitude; 4) I am monitoring because past function was erratic, but this resolved a few months ago. Sorry to waste everyone's time. This is the first and last posting from me on this site.


You may want to check the ambient temperature around the freezer during that time. In particular where the freezer may be located in a garage or basement that may be influenced by changes in the outdoor temperature.
You may also want to review usage of the freezer, i.e. opening and closings, during that time. Faster cycling could be an indicator of something like the door not closing tightly and the internal temperature not being retained like normal.
Lastly it is always possible that the thermostatic control in the freezer may be having a problem. For this I suggest continue to monitor more and watch for factors like above and if those do not apply then consider replacement or the freezer temperature controller if you see this behavior again one or more times.

Michael: Thanks again for your prior answer. I posted my response where I did because I could not include the ambient temperature graph in a comment box. Thanks for moving it.

@BradleyWoodruff - Putting additional information into a comment box would not have been correct even if it would have accepted a graphic. It belonged in your question as I merged it.
